# Using Boost Python to access a specific function which references other classes

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I'm a C++ novice but I have a C++ file that I'm trying to create a Python module from to access a specific function run in C++. I'm trying to use Boost Python in order to do this, but I'm only interested in being able to access the `get_equities()` function, defined within the file.

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "omp/EquityCalculator.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace omp;
using namespace std;

// Function prototype (declaration)
vector<double> get_equities(vector<string> args);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);
    vector<double> equities;
    equities = get_equities(args);
};

vector<double> get_equities(vector<string> args) {

    int argc = args.size();

    string board_string = args[1];

    EquityCalculator eq;
    vector<CardRange> ranges;
    for( int i = 2; i < argc; i++ ) {
        ranges.push_back(args[i]);
    };

    uint64_t board = CardRange::getCardMask(board_string);

    eq.start(ranges, board);
    cout << "running" << endl;
    eq.wait();

    vector<double> result;

    auto r = eq.getResults();
    // 2 to 4; 2 to 3
    //todo: 
    for( int i = 2; i < argc; i++ ) {
        result.push_back(r.equity[i - 2]);
    }
    cout << result[0] << endl;
    return result;

}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cpp_equity)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("get_equities", get_equities);

}
```

This refers to a separate class `EquityCalculator` (which refers to a number of other classes via recursive includes).

Following the tutorial, I was hoping that I would only have to declare this function, however when trying to use a setup.py I get some errors:

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:0:
omp/EquityCalculator.h:76:21: error: ‘std::function’ has not been declared
                std::function<void(const Results&)> callback = nullptr,
                     ^~~~~~~~
omp/EquityCalculator.h:76:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                std::function<void(const Results&)> callback = nullptr,
                             ^
omp/EquityCalculator.h:202:10: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     std::function<void(const Results& results)> mCallback;
          ^~~~~~~~
omp/EquityCalculator.h:74:10: error: default argument missing for parameter 6 of ‘bool omp::EquityCalculator::start
(const std::vector<omp::CardRange>&, uint64_t, uint64_t, bool, double, int)’
     bool start(const std::vector<CardRange>& handRanges, uint64_t boardCards = 0, uint64_t deadCards = 0,
          ^~~~~
```

Does this mean I need to declare the `EquityCalculator`class and any accessed methods as well? What about the other classes that `EquityCalculator` uses?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the note on , adding this to the .h file solved my issue. I can now run setup.py successfully.

However - when I import the generated .so into Python, I get:

```
ImportError: ./cpp_equity.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3omp13CombinedRangeC1Ev
```

Am I missing something in my setup.py?

Do I need to add the 'omp' directory somewhere, in the Extension() args in the setup.py file for example?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `‘std::function’ has not been declared` --> have you included `<functional>` in your `EquityCalculator.h`?

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! This solved this issue. However I can't import the generated so file into Python - see edit above. Any ideas?